# Java Thread : Given program isn't behaving properly

Tags: java, multithreading, shared-memory, thread-priority

```
import java.lang.*;

class MyRun implements Runnable 
{
  public static int start = 0;
  public void run() 
  {
    int myCounter = 0;
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is waiting on start flag");
    while(start<1)
    {
      // just waiting...        
    }
    while(myCounter<5) 
    {
      myCounter++;
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" : "+myCounter);
      try 
      {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch(Exception ex) {}
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" stopped and start="+start);
  }
}

public class test 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
    {
      int p = i+1;
      threads[i] = new Thread(new MyRun());
      threads[i].setName("TH"+p);
      threads[i].setPriority(p);
      threads[i].start();
    }
    MyRun.start=1; // signaling GO
  }
}
```

Output:

```
TH1 is waiting on start flag
TH2 is waiting on start flag
TH3 is waiting on start flag
TH4 is waiting on start flag
TH5 is waiting on start flag
TH6 is waiting on start flag
TH8 is waiting on start flag
TH7 is waiting on start flag
TH9 is waiting on start flag
TH10 is waiting on start flag
TH10 : 1
TH10 : 2
TH10 : 3
TH10 : 4
TH10 : 5
TH10 stopped and start=1
```

I'm expecting output from all threads as start flag is set to 1 but only thread with name TH10 is executed.

Can you help me to find out whats happening in this code with threads exactly ?

What i'm trying to do with such code ?

Ans : Trying to analyze priority of threads (clearing my thread concepts specially multi-threading with shared static variable over runnable).

Thanks in advance, let me know if you need any info from my side.

Update : consider all threads as horses, and when MyRun.start is set to 1 (it should be considered as GO signal for all horses) but only the 10th horse is running after signal.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"Here's a bunch of my code, please debug it for me"_ are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.

Comment: I think it is a suitable question, since it is about a specific problem und not just "my code does not work"

Comment: @JimGarrison With all respect, i'm not asking to debug it but it only happens when priorities are there, without priorities its perfect. So i'm missing something from concept of thread priority,,, so need help in that area.

Comment: you might want to look into the `volatile` keyword

Comment: @MohanSharma _"Can you help me to find out logical error from this code "_ -- sure sounds like "debug this for me". Did you try using the debugger?

Comment: Let me give this little advice: Think about the variable `MyRun` you are using at the end of the thread starts and to which thread it is bound to. The other threads are not spoken to because of the priority you set on the last one. The highest priority wins and get's executed first. > The highest-priority runnable thread keeps running until: it ceases to be a thread.
Then, the scheduler selects a new thread to run. The highest-priority remaining thread is picked among those that are runnable.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Thanks i'm looking into it. I'll let you know if it around my question

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes i've tried it using debugger on netbeans

Comment: @nico Thanks, but its not picking next highest priority thread as in my case. TH9 or TH8 should be speak there. But program is waiting for something.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thanks for telling me that debug term, i am changing it :D

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer I think volatile is not problem of this question, but let me why you think of that ?

Comment: When you debug and `TH10` prints the message `TH10 stopped and start=1` what is happening in the debugger? Where does he jump to or where does it stop? It sounds like there is something in MyRun that's bothers the thread to be released. It is possible to give a hint to the scheduler that this thread can be freed with `thread.yield()`
> A hint to the scheduler that the current thread is willing to yield its current use of a processor.

Comment: @Nico Its waiting on first while loop. Something weird because when TH10 stopped its shows that value of start variable is 1.

Comment: Ok so you could try calling `Thread.yield()` after printing `TH is stopped`. If everything is correctly working the thread TH9 should start next. If you want them to all run at the same time you shouldn't work with priority though. Priority will let them get handled one after one from the Thread sheduler.

Comment: @Nico okay let me try that. Can you please explain what yield method will do here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136927/discussion-between-nico-and-mohan-sharma).

Comment: @Nico yes you're right about your priority conclusion but what I'm exploring is that some horses may have better health (in terms of priority)

Comment: @Nico thanks for such kind support... but right now I'm in lecture... so dont able concentrate on chat...

Comment: No problem we can use it as comments. I will get a notification when you write in there. It's just getting too much comments and I don't want a mod to get angry ;) :)

Comment: @Nico thanks its working without priorities... but it also worka without that GO signal loop plus priorities is there.

Comment: Also you could try to use a ThreadGroup instead of an Array of threads. by definition: Thread groups provide a mechanism for collecting multiple threads into a single object and manipulating those threads all at once, rather than individually.

To me it seems that in the Thread the variable start is not resolved correctly in the loop. Or more over that the loop does not what you want. It always confuses me to see an `if` or `while` without `{ }`

Comment: @Nico thanks.. threadgroup is new concept for me... let me try that also. Hehhehehehe for if and while without {}.... i think I'm not confused wid that... but let me try to change that also, may be it works.

Comment: Your code is working.
I can see all the threads running printing THX stopped and start=1

Comment: `volatile` might be necessary to ensure all threads see the change of `start`.
Regardless: You might want to learn about Executors and various way on how to synchronize threads. A simple `CountDownLatch` might be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has at least two problems:

- it uses a public unsynchronized variable (`start`) which is always a code smell as far as multi-threading is concerned => there is no guarantee that your threads see the correct value for `start`
- it does not wait for Threads to complete their task

The proper way to achieve this kind of things is by using paradigms in the `java.util.concurrent` package. In this case this would be `CountDownLatch`es

The example provided in the Javadoc is actually very close to what you are trying to achieve here (start all threads together, wait for them to complete), so I am reproducing it. `MyRun` is the `Worker` below; in `doWork()`, please implement the content of your `run()` method

The `startSignal` "latches" the start of all the threads which are all "awaiting" it.
The `doneSignal` "latches" the end of the program (the `main`) once the end of all threads has been "counted down"

```
 class Driver { // ...
   void main() throws InterruptedException {
     CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
     CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(N);

     for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // create and start threads
       new Thread(new Worker(startSignal, doneSignal)).start();

     doSomethingElse();            // don't let run yet
     startSignal.countDown();      // let all threads proceed
     doSomethingElse();
     doneSignal.await();           // wait for all to finish
   }
 }

 class Worker implements Runnable {
   private final CountDownLatch startSignal;
   private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;
   Worker(CountDownLatch startSignal, CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
      this.startSignal = startSignal;
      this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
   }
   public void run() {
      try {
        startSignal.await();
        doWork();
        doneSignal.countDown();
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} // return;
   }

   void doWork() { ... }
 }
```

Comment: i accepted your answer as it doing same thing appropriately... but still i'm not able to figure out what was the (exactly)problem with program i've given.